# Dynamic Work shifts in Tabular model

Tags: ssas, powerbi, ssas-tabular

I have a static calendar hierarchy in SSAS Tabular model with minutes, hours, days. This way I can do cool metric grouping by dates like:

```
2017-01-01 45
2017-01-02 3
2017-01-03 17
```

I want to be able to do groupings by *work shifts* which are no more then 24 hours long. I could extend my calendar hierarchy with static shifts. But I need *work shifts* to be user definable on the fly.

For example user can set 22-hour shift from 03:00 to 01:00.

What approach should I take to include dynamic shifts into calendar hierarchy?

Comment: Do shifts always start and end at round hours? Can there be two shifts during the same day (01:00-11:00 & 12:00-20:00)?

Comment: They start at round hours. Two shifts starting same day are not possible. But one might end at 03:00 next day and other start two hours later.